# Set time to send out HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httprequest

Is there a way in Rails to send out a request at a certain time?

I'm using an external credit card charging API, and I want to adjust each monthly subscription based on how many referrals they have (10% each, 10 referrals max).  The API has a beta referral system built in, but it doesn't seem to work the way I need it to.  Plus, there are just too many unknowns that I'd rather not get into at the moment. I just want to get it up and working, and since my system is fairly simple, I'd rather just do it manually.

There's a billing date for each subscription, and what I want to do is just manually adjust the price of the subscription based on how many active users there are containing the referral code of the user being charged. I'd like to just send out this request to the API just before they're billed.  Like sometime around `subscription.next_billing_at - 1.minute`.

Then just set the `subscription.price` to `price - (price * (User.where(referral_code: current_user_code)).count / 10)`.

I'm aware this is far from an optimal approach, considering the amount of extra requests being made each month, but since we're small right now, it shouldn't be a problem. Again, it's just a temporary solution so we can get things running now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options which directly answer your question.

Write a rake task and run it daily with cron via the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). If you take this approach, you will have to have the task just load all subscriptions which are due to be billed in the next cycle and update them as required.

Alternatively, use something like [Resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler), which would allow you to run some task at next_billing_at - 1.minute or something.

But if you are small, why not just update the price every time a new referral is created using a callback? Unless there are specific rate or query limits on this API, I doubt a card processor is going to be affected by the traffic you generate. Of course if there are other requirements, like, a referral only applies after a month or something like that, you are going to be stuck with one of the first 2 options, and the Cron + Rake task is probably the best solution in that case.